Parse embedded XML in the log with Logtash
logs are from filebeat to logstash and I write a pattern to parse them.developers added logs that have embeded xml inside logs and here is a sample :
2024-07-08 15:18:35,608 INFO |body=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ss2:normal xmlns:ns2="http://service..com/">
    <context>
        <data>
            <key>ADDRESS</key>
            <value>0.0.0.0</value>
        </data>
        <data>
            <key>ssid</key>
            <value>d1d71e02-25ff-1</value>
        </data>
        <data>
            <key>m-id</key>
            <value>25440fb</value>
        </data>
    </context>
    <request>
        <amount>50</amount>
    </request>
</ss2:normal>

how can I parse body section and retrieve values in json format considering that xml in body is dynamiclaly changed by type of services?
